# What does the adjective "big" modify in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives

In this sentence, does big modify *basketball player* or just *player*?

> He is a big basketball player.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Unless he plays with big basketballs, it modifies player. In the phrase, *a big white dog*, the word *big* would tell you nothing about the colour of the dog, only its size.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Context* is essential to any understanding of meaning. It is quite impossible to answer your question without it. For example, I might use the phrase *big basketball*, for example, to refer to a highly flamboyant or kinetic style of play, or elsewhere to large-scale, systematized basketball programs as in the NBA or NCAA D-I.

Comment: The salient meaning is that it modifies "basketball player".

Answer (score 1):

This would depend heavily on the context.

Here it modifies "basketball player":

> The girls were in awe. Everybody knew who he was. He was a **big basketball player**.

And here just "player":

> All the players on the team were short except him. He stood out. He was a **big** basketball **player**.

Comment: Wouldn't it just modify player in both situations? If you wanted to make big modify "basketball player" I feel like you would have to hyphenate it like "basketball-player."

Comment: @Jim: Basketballist. Basketballer.

Comment: [Big-time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big-time) basketball player perhaps.